Give side effect to only first call of Pytest patched function
I have a function that renders HTML templates. In case exception is thrown during rendering of a given template, a default template will be rendered (simplified version of the function below):
def main(path_to_template):
    try:
        return render_template(path_to_template)
    except Exception:
        return render_template('default.html')

I would like to test the exception block.
In my test function I wanted to patch render_template, so that it has an Exception side effect.
This must be limited to the first call only however, since I want the second call to return whatever render_template is doing.
Is it possible to create such a test?
I tried the following solutions, but none work:
def test_main():
    mocker.patch("path.to.render_template", side_effect=Exception("mock exception"))
    main("some_path")

The above is the first approach and it will raise Exception in both calls, hence not test what I want to test.
def test_main():
    mocker.patch("path.to.render_template", side_effect=[Exception("mock exception"), None])
    main("some_path")

The above also does not work because the return of render_template is not supposed to be None.
def custom_side_effect(*args):
    if args[0] == "some_path":
        raise Exception("mock exception")
    else:
        return render_template(args[0])

def test_main():
    mocker.patch("path.to.render_template", side_effect=custom_side_effect)
    main("some_path")

The last one results in a circular exception throwing and I have to kill the test run.
The problem seems to be something standard with an easy solution.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue and can suggest the way to solve it?
EDIT 1:
The original test is a functional test using Selenium, where I want to test a scenario of a server error that should result in displaying HTTP 500 Error page.
Below the original function under test:
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def pages(request):
    context = {}
    try:
        # remove trailing slash to determine a template
        path = request.path.rstrip("/")
        load_template = path.split("/")[-1]
        if load_template == "admin":
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("admin:index"))
        context["segment"] = load_template
        html_template = loader.get_template("home/" + load_template)
    except template.TemplateDoesNotExist as e:
        html_template = loader.get_template("home/page-404.html")
    except Exception as e:
        html_template = loader.get_template("home/page-500.html")
    return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))

EDIT 2:
As a temporary solution I decided to do small refactoring.
def load_home_page(path_to_template):
    return loader.get_template(path_to_template)


def load_404_page():
    return loader.get_template("home/page-404.html")


def load_500_page():
    return loader.get_template("home/page-500.html")

Then I only patch load_home_page function.
I don't think this is the best solution, so it would be great to see something cleaner.

The above also does not work because the return of render_template is not supposed to be None ->
Then can't you return mocked data but in the expected format?

@justTesting the example is simplified. The original test is a functional test using Selenium where I want to test a scenario of a server error that should result in displaying HTTP 500 Error page. Mocking render_template is not the goal in this test. I just want it to throw an Exception when called the first time and run when called the second time. I added the original function being tested.

In the answer I don't use pytest but only the standard package unittest. I hope that this isn't a problem for you.
However you will find the definition of side_effect and if you want you can adapt my code to pytest.
Code example in my system
I have created 3 files all are saved in the same directory.
File main.py
from other_module import render_template

def main(path_to_template):
    try:
        return render_template(path_to_template)
    except Exception:
        return render_template('default.html')

It contains exactly your function main(). In this file I have inserted the import:
from other_module import render_template

so I can execute the code. Obviously in your system the import is different.
File other_module.py
To be able to execute the code in my system I have created a module called other_module.py and inside it I have defined a function render_template() as following:
# content of the file 'other_module.py'

def render_template(path_to_template):
    print(f"Called real render_template with arg = '{path_to_template}'")
    return path_to_template

The function prints a message every times it is executed and return the argument passed to it.
File test_main.py
The third (most important) file is test_main.py defined as following:
import unittest
from unittest import mock

from other_module import render_template
from main import main

def custom_side_effect(path_to_template):
    print(f"Called custom_side_effect with arg '{path_to_template}'")
    return render_template(path_to_template)

class TestRenderTemplate(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_main(self):
        other_path = "other_path"
        with mock.patch('main.render_template') as mock_render_template:
            # note that the list used to define side_effect is composed by 3 items
            mock_render_template.side_effect = [Exception, custom_side_effect('default.html'), custom_side_effect(other_path)]
            # the call of main() causes the call of render_tamplate() for 2 times (the second time it is called in the 'except' block)
            self.assertEqual('default.html', main("some_path"))
            # the second call to main() causes the third called to render_template()
            self.assertEqual(other_path, main(other_path))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

Output of the execution
The execution of the test produces the following output:
Called custom_side_effect with arg 'default.html'
Called real render_template with arg = 'default.html'
Called custom_side_effect with arg 'other_path'
Called real render_template with arg = 'other_path'

.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK

The output shows that:

the first time it is called render_template() by main(), it is raised an Exception caused by the definition of side_effect:

mock_render_template.side_effect = [Exception, custom_side_effect('default.html'), custom_side_effect(other_path)]


render_template() is called 2 times by custom_side_effect(); this is showed by the fact that the message Called real render_template with arg ... follows the message Called custom_side_effect with arg...

Never call the real render_template: change custom_side_effect
Above my definition of custom side effect is not very different from yours. In it you have called the real function render_template().
The previous definition of custom_side_effect() is not the best. I suggest you to use the following definition where the real function render_template() is never called:
def custom_side_effect(path_to_template):
    print(f"Called custom_side_effect with arg '{path_to_template}'")
    #return render_template(path_to_template)
    return path_to_template

In this way the output of the execution shows that only the function custom_side_effect() is executed, but the core of the test is unchanged.
Output of the execution with the new custom_side_effect:
Called custom_side_effect with arg 'default.html'
Called custom_side_effect with arg 'other_path'
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK


Use wraps to make a real call to the function when you want a real output.

wraps: Item for the mock object to wrap. If wraps is not None then calling the Mock will pass the call through to the wrapped object (returning the real result). Attribute access on the mock will return a Mock object that wraps the corresponding attribute of the wrapped object (so attempting to access an attribute that doesn’t exist will raise an AttributeError).

As you want the 1st call to the function to be patched and 2nd call to be the real call, you should pass unittest.mock.DEFAULT to side_effect in order for side_effect to pass the real call to the wrapped object.
from unittest import mock

from path.to import render_template


def test_main():
    with mock.patch(
            target="path.to.render_template",
            side_effect=[Exception("mock exception"), mock.DEFAULT],
            wraps=render_template
    ):
    main("some_path")

side_effect, return_value and wraps follow the order of precedence when you use them together. unittest.mock.DEFAULT is a special object which is ignored by the side_effect and the order of precedence moves to the next precedence which in your case should be wraps.

If the value being returned by side_effect is DEFAULT, it is ignored and the order of precedence moves to the successor to obtain the value to return.

Your mistake was you passed None to side_effect instead of passing DEFAULT  and you didn't use wraps to pass the real call to the function.
